# How can I place maxLength in TextFormField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Currently, the limit counter is placed below, but I would like to have it inside the TextFormField at the end. How can I do that?

```dart
        child: TextFormField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      maxLength: 50,
                      validator: (String? value) {
                        if (value!.trim().isEmpty) {
                          return 'error';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (String? value) {
                        name = value!.trim();
                      },
                    ),
```

Comment: could you include the ui you want?

Comment: @eamirho3ein ui wise its like the answer below, thanks for reaching out tho! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/maxLength.html) for the `maxLength` property on a TextFormField, you have no control over where that is displayed. You can set up a similar counter using the `onChanged` property of the `TextFormField` and the `suffixText` property of the `inputDecorator` [property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html) of the `TextFormField` ([documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html)). This requires that the TextFormField be part of a `StatefulWidget`.

```dart
String counterStr = "0";
....
child: TextFormField(
                  controller: nameController,
                  maxLength: 50,
                  inputDecorator: InputDecorator(
                    suffixText: counterStr
                  ),
                  validator: (String? value) {
                    if (value!.trim().isEmpty) {
                      return 'error';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (String? value) {
                    name = value!.trim();
                  },
                  onChanged: (){
                    setState((){
                      counterStr = nameController.text.length.toString();
                    });
                  }
                ),
```

Comment: This is working just like I want it to - Thanks!
I did change the suffixText to '$counterStr/50' to still be able to show the users how many characters they can enter